React App deployed on GoDaddy not rendering properly
I have deployed a React app on GoDaddy, but I'm facing issues with the rendering. The background image loads correctly, but other content is not visible. I have checked the network requests, and all the necessary files are being fetched properly.
I have verified the HTML structure, and the <div id="root"> element is present, but it seems that the content inside it is not being rendered.I have verified that there are no errors in the console. Can someone please help me understand why the content is not rendering properly?
I have included my App.jsx and index.html files for reference. Can someone please guide me on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
Thank you!
app.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Attendance from "./components/Attendance";
import Locations from "./components/Locations";
import Sampling from "./components/Sampling";
import Questions from "./components/Questions";
import Logout from "./components/auth/Logout";
import Aboutus from "./components/Aboutus";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage';
import UploadImage from './components/UploadImage';
function App() {
  const logged = useSelector((state) => state.auth.status);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={logged ? <Navigate to="/home" /> : <Login />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        {logged ? (
          <>
            <Route path="/attendance" element={<Attendance />} />
            <Route path="/locations" element={<Locations />} />
            <Route path="/sampling" element={<Sampling />} />
            <Route path="/questions" element={<Questions />} />
            <Route path="/aboutus" element={<Aboutus />} />
            <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />
            <Route path="/upload-image" element={<UploadImage />} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
        )}
      </Routes>
      <footer></footer>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
   
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>

.htacess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.html">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>


hello all solved my issue used HashRouter instaid of BrowserRouter, working pefectly fine
